# Error while accessing Django model in admin view

Tags: django, postgresql

I was trying to access objects of StockDailyPrice model from my Django Admin view. But I'm seeing the following error while doing so

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/api/stockdailyprice/

Django Version: 4.0.3
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'api',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders']
Installed Middleware:
['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 1: ..."api_stock" ON ("api_stockdailyprice"."symbol_id" = "api_sto...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 2063, in changelist_view
    "selection_note": _("0 of %(cnt)s selected") % {"cnt": len(cl.result_list)},
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 302, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/bharathkumargundala/otsiot/crosspoints-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/api/stockdailyprice/
Exception Value: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 1: ..."api_stock" ON ("api_stockdailyprice"."symbol_id" = "api_sto...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

My Django Models' code is like this

```
from django.db import models


class Stock(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    exchange = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Undefined')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.symbol) + ":" + str(self.exchange)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('symbol', 'exchange',)


class StockDailyPrice(models.Model):
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateField()
    open = models.FloatField()
    high = models.FloatField()
    low = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('symbol', 'date',)
```

The same models were working fine when I was using sqlite3 with Django earlier. Only by changing the Database, this error is popping up which is not solvable from only Django point of view

Did anyone in this community face similar situation?

Comment: Just to make sure, have you run the makemigration and migrate commands? If yes, would you mind to check if replacing DO_NOTHING with CASCADE causes any difference?

Comment: @MaGaroo There were no pending migrations
Even after changing on_delete to CASCADE, the same error pops-up

Comment: Hmmm... Could you say what Django and psycopg2 versions are you using? I implemented this code with the latest version and it hasn't encountered any problems so far.

Or have you used a custom ModelAdmin for `StockDailyPrice` in `admin.py`?

Comment: I tried again with 
class StockDailyPrice(models.Model):
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Now there is no error. Issue resolved